# How is Uub related to Maitibu?

Tags: dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-series

Dragon Ball fans out there, please explain why Goku says that Uub is related to Maitibu. Please solve my childhood mystery.

Comment: Is Maitibu a person? Because he is not one of the DBZ characters. Are you referring to Buu by any chance?

Comment: I'm getting the feeling that it's supposed to be Majin Buu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We know that warriors can recognize someone's aura by feeling it.

In Chapter 519, Goku asks Buu to use his magic to fight Uub. But we all know Goku isn't the smart type, he just has this feeling. Goku is the one who fought the most with Buu, its probably normal he's the one who's able to recognize him.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Uub is the reincarnation of Kid Buu

> He is the Human reincarnation of Kid Buu. Due to being the positive
>   reincarnation of the completely evil Kid Buu, his name is a result of
>   reversing "Buu".

source: http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Uub